# OAuth Facebook Authentication with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-authentication

So I guess this question is sort of two folds

1. What should I store when granted Facebook OAuth rights into my User Domain Entity (facebook userid? or token? or both or something else)
2. Can I just generally secure the ASP.NET Web API with a DelegatingHandler to read for the access token?

Currently my core architecture is as follows:

- MyApp.Domain : My domain models in a Class Library Project
- MyApp.DataAccess: My Repositories and Entity Framework Contexts
- MyApp.WebAPI : ASP.NET Web API Project for a RESTful Service

My Clients are

- MyApp.Website: ASP.NET MVC 4 Website
- MyApp.iPhoneApp - Native iOS App for the iPhone
- MyApp.AndroidApp - Native Android App

Comment: This question should provide some insight:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207673/web-api-open-oauthdotnetopenauth-mvc-4